# How do I use a textblock for navigation?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am new to windows dev't and C#, how do make those texts i posted in the code navigate to another xaml page?

Thanks

```
<StackPanel>    
    <TextBlock Text="contact us"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
               FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="help" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
               FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is this a windows phone 8.1 app?

Comment: its a windows 8.0 app

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Based on what you've described, one way would be to link [an event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596(v=vs.110).aspx) to a [Window.Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748324(v=vs.100).aspx) method, to show the window. See the links I've provided here for some examples and thoughts, but basically you could insert this into a `TextBlock` to cause a method to happen when you do a mouse-click on it:

```
<TextBlock Text="contact us"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
           MouseUp="MethodToCallNameHere"/>
```

When you write this in XAML, highlight "MethodToCallNameHere" and press F12, and it will automatically insert a method for you in that Window's code-behind. You can then put in your new window's class there with `.Show()`.

For example, if you wanted to show a new window that is an `AboutWindow` class (i.e., when you created another XAML window, you named it "AboutWindow"), you could highlight "MethodToCallNameHere" and press F12.

Then, in the created method in the code-behind, you could make it look something like this, to open "AboutWindow" window when the `TextBlock` is clicked:

```
    private void MethodToCallNameHere(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // instantiate the new Window's class
        AboutWindow aboutWindow = new AboutWindow();
        // call the .Show() method to show the new window
        aboutWindow.Show();
    }
```

I'd recommend looking through MS's online (and free) documentation on WPF applications [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx). It's been very helpful to me as I've been learning.